# DEF file format for Windows __stdcall DLLs? (*.def -> lib.exe -> *.lib)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, function

I'm trying to recreate import libraries (.lib) for some Microsoft DLLs (I want to remove a few functions). It's possible to create lib files for dlls by using lib.exe on a def file. However it seems to be difficult to do that for __stdcall functions.

How to do this? Note: I have access to the dll and the original lib file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating an MSVC import library from a DLL that uses stdcall](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393178/creating-an-msvc-import-library-from-a-dll-that-uses-stdcall)

Comment: You can do it if you have the .pdb file.  Which you can get from the Microsoft symbol server.  Copy it to the same folder as the .dll and Dumpbin.exe /exports will show you the original name, .def style.  This otherwise sounds like a lot of effort for little gain.  If you want to *replace* an export then just link your own version ahead of the import .lib

Answer (score 2):

You fell into the trap of asking a question rather than describing a problem. You cannot reliably create a LIB from an EXE (since it won't have the appropriate decorations). But fortunately that's not what you actually want to do.

All you really want to do is remove objects from a LIB. [Use the /REMOVE option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e17b885t%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).